# Archivo de datos csv como array en Python

Tags: python, array, base-de-datos, csv

Hola a todos tengo una duda, tengo un archivo de datos de 4 columnas (tiempo,x,y,z) e hice un array para dividir el tiempo en pequeñas partes/franjas y quiero contar los números de datos que hay por parte/franja. Pensaba usar un contador con un while pero me marca error por la cantidad de columnas, hay manera de hacer el archivo csv un array?

Comment: Podrias publicar que llevas hecho hasta ahora?, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Además podrías mostrar el formato de tu csv

Comment: Para obtener un array apartir de un csv  puedes usar numpy de la siguiente manera:

   `import numpy as np`
    
    `tiempo, x, y, z = np.genfromtxt('archivo.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True)`

Para contar el numero de elementos únicamente usar `len()` sobre el array que gustes.

Comment: Tengo lo siguiente: nsis= read_csv('datos.csv', index_col=0), i=0, part=[], u=mn, for i in range(n): part.append(u),  u += it, print part, x0=nsis(1,8999). while True: x0 += 1, if x0 < part: print x0, continue else: break 
Uso el paquete numpy y pandas

Comment: @CarlosRosales **[edit] tu pregunta**, los comentarios son temporales. Puedes ver [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos

Answer (score 2):

La libreria que te sirve para leer es **csv** y para obtener los datos y medirlos puedes usar un `for` y `len`.
Cuando obtengas la información necesaria, insertala en tu array simplemente y manejala como quieras.

```python
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('archivo.csv', 'rb'))
for row in (reader):
    row.split('...indica el delimitador...')
    tiempo,x,y,z = row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3] 
# Aquí me sale duda si quieres contar la cantidad de 
# datos que tienes por columna o por 'celda' dentro del dato
# Para cantidad de datos por celda:
    print len(tiempo), len(x), len(y), len(z)
# Para la cantidad de datos por columna
print len(reader[...numero de columna...])
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar pandas, a mi me funciono.

primero crea un `DataFrame` con tus datos usando:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[x],'y':[y],'t':[t]})
```

después guardalo como `CSV` usando pandas:

```
df.to_csv('directorio donde lo vas a guardar')
```

para preguntar el valor de tu pregunta usa `len`('encabezado de cada columna')